# What is Apache Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch

Please clear me on what is apache lucene? As for a I know it is search engine so please advise  me how does apache lucene used in search

and what is elastic search ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/index.html) is a documentation of Apache Lucene and I'm sure you will find what it is. ElasticSearch is search server based on Apache Lucene.